# While statement not working?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int number;
    float cost;
    char beverage;

    bool validBeverage;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    do
    {
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "Hot Beverage Menu" << endl << endl;
        cout << "A: Coffee         $1.00" << endl;
        cout << "B: Tea            $ .75" << endl;
        cout << "C: Hot Chocolate  $1.25" << endl;
        cout << "D: Cappuccino     $2.50" << endl <<endl << endl;

        cout << "Enter the beverage A,B,C, or D you desire" << endl;
        cout << "Enter E to exit the program" << endl << endl;
        cin>>beverage;
        while(beverage!='A'||beverage!='B'||beverage!='C'||beverage!='D'||beverage!='E'||beverage!='a'||beverage!='b'||beverage!='c'||
        beverage!='d'||beverage!='e')
        {
            cout<<"Your selection is invalid please re-enter ";
            cin>>beverage;
        }

        switch(beverage)
        {
        case 'a':  validBeverage = true;
        case 'A':  validBeverage = true;
        case 'b':  validBeverage = true;
        case 'B':  validBeverage = true;
        case 'c':  validBeverage = true;
        case 'C':  validBeverage = true;
        case 'd':  validBeverage = true;
        case 'D':  validBeverage = true;
                   break;
        default:   validBeverage = false;
        }

        if (validBeverage == true)
        {
            cout << "How many cups would you like?" << endl;
        cin>>number;
        }
        // Fill in the code to begin a switch statement
        switch(beverage)
        {
        case 'a': cost = number * 1.0;
        case 'A': cost = number * 1.0;
                cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
                break;
        case 'b': cost = number * 0.75;
        case 'B': cost = number * 0.75;
                cout<< "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
                break;
        case 'c': cost = number * 1.25;
        case 'C': cost = number * 1.25;
                cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
                break;
        case 'd': cost = number * 2.50;
        case 'D': cost = number * 2.50;
                cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
        case 'e': cout << " Please come again" << endl;
        case 'E': cout << " Please come again" << endl;
                break;
        default:cout << " You have enter an invalid selection"<<endl;
                cout << " Try again please" << endl;
        }

    }while(beverage!='e'||beverage!='E');
}
```

I have tried to run this program but it always gives me that I have enter an invalid selection.
I have tried modifying the while loop but it did not work;Is it the while loop?;
Also in not sure if I have written the while statement in the do while correctly.

Comment: `||` is OR. Of course `beverage` will differ from `A` OR differ from `B` or .... You wanted `&&`

Comment: Code style comment: you are overusing case dropthroughs. Like if you do beverage 'e', it will print "Please come again" twice.

Comment: @Almo And, worse still, do the multiplications twice.

Comment: Well, the multiplications are small operations and don't alter the output. So I think the couts being duplicated are worse. :)

Comment: Debugging 101: If your big block of code doesn't work as intended, break it into smaller bits of code (or print out intermediate results) to check which parts **do** work as intended, and which ones **do not**. *Check your assumptions.* Corollary: What did you try, yourself?

Comment: @Almo Of course. I somehow read it as them cumulating instead of overwriting.

Comment: @Angew I figured. I thought it was messing up the values as well. Had to look twice to see what it was doing. Often, if you have to look twice at code to see what it's doing, there's a problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

Take this condition as an example, the same problem is in others as well.

```
while (beverage!='e'||beverage!='E');
```

A character is either not equal to `'e'`, or it is equal to `'e'`, in which case it's not equal to `'E'`, so the condition is always true.

What you want is logical and.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
while(beverage!='e'||beverage!='E'); // Condition becomes true always
```

to

```
while(beverage!='e'&& beverage!='E');
```

And similarly replace all `||` by `&&` in first while loop conditional expression

```
while(beverage!='A' && beverage!='B' &&beverage!='C'&& beverage!='D' && beverage!='E' && beverage!='a' && beverage!='b' && beverage!='c' &&
     beverage!='d' && beverage!='e')
```